# Python converting array values to separate array

Tags: python

I have a python array that looks like this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I want it to look like this: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

How  do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are talking about lists. This should work:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

out = [[i] for i in l]
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this using append method of list

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_list = [] 
for i in list_a:
    new_list.append([i])
```